# Living family members of Samuel Baumgartner

Tags: switzerland

I’m looking for living family members that are still living in Switzerland. Back in 1982 a family member came to the United State’s and brought over a family tree. I would love to connect with living family members to add to our tree.

My 4th great-grandfather Samuel Baumgartner, Birth 22 November 1807 in Rapperswil, Bern, Switzerland Death 07-April 1892 Waukesha Wisconsin USA. He married Magdalena Schori Birth 2 November 1812 Death 1894. She was also from Rapperswil, Bern, Switzerland.

From stories I remember Samuel came to the USA with a couple of his children and left Magdalena in Switzerland with a couple of children. I believe some of the children were.

- Magdalena born 1835
- Nicklaus born 1841
- John born 1843
- Jacob born 1845
- Bendicht born 1848
- Friedrich born 1851

They were all born in Rapperswil, Bern, Switzerland. I don’t know what children stayed in Switzerland and what one came to the USA

This is my grandma’s side of the family

Answer (score 3):

As a start you could have a look at the church records of the Canton Bern which are available digitally up until 1875 at the State Archives ([announcement](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ref.ch%2Fnews%2Fstaatsarchiv-in-bern-stellt-tausende-kirchenbuecher-online%2F)). Rapperswil can be found at https://www.query.sta.be.ch/detail.aspx?ID=220197 ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.query.sta.be.ch%2Fdetail.aspx%3FID%3D220197)). Use first "To entry at a lower level" and then "To the next entry in the archive plan" on the left to cycle through the entries. What will make it a bit difficult is

- that records are only availble up to 1875
- you will have to read old German handwriting

At least the names are in Latin script so it is a bit easier to get to the interesting entries.

Also a casual [search](https://tel.search.ch/index.en.html?was=baumgartner&wo=Rapperswil%20(SG)%20SG) for "Baumgartner" in Rapperswil yielded some results, but those not necessarily need to be related to you. I also found an old [address book](https://www.e-rara.ch/bes_1/content/titleinfo/1397203) ([Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.e-rara.ch%2Fbes_1%2Fcontent%2Ftitleinfo%2F1397203)) of the Canton Bern from 1836 which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same family tree from 1982 and it would be great if we could work together to start a digitalised version of our family tree.

I am Daniel, son of Edwin who is son of Werner who is son of Hermann who is son of Bendicht who is son of Samuel.

I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

I also have Baumgartners in my tree, though not in Switzerland.  Mine were in Bad Krozingen, Germany, with my 4x GGM Walpurga Baumgartner (b 1792, d 1873) moving to Philadelphia.  Her parents were Johannes Franciscus Baumgartner and Maria Anna Motsch.  Johannes' parents were Joannes Baumgartner and Catharina Höcklin.  Bad Krozingen is about 150 km north of Rapperswil, just on the other side of the border.  I've not seen that family tree, but would be quite interested in knowing if there is a connection.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Rothenbuehler.   Some of same history.  Rudolf Zanger 1839 who married Magdalena Baumgartner in Switzerland, who was the daughter of Samuel Baumgartner and Magdalena Schori of Switzerland.  Zanger later settled in Wisconsin and then Iowa.  Child married a rothenbuehler .